# Footnotes in wrapfig environment

Tags: footnotes, octavo

I would like to put some text in wrap fig floats because I  found this to be the only way I can have the regular text wrapping around it. However, it seems I cannot use any footnote in the text within the environment. Is this a limitation? Is there a workaround?

```
\documentclass[crown, 11pt]{octavo}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{reledmac}


\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}

%To have critical footnotes before familiar footnotes
\fnpos{critical-familiar}
\Xbeforenotes[A]{1.8em}
\beforenotesX[A]{1.8em}
\beforenotesX[B]{1.8em}
\Xafterrule[A]{7pt}
\afterruleX[A]{7pt}
\afterruleX[B]{7pt}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}



\begin{document}
\section{Something}

This is sample text. \footnote{This is it} This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. 

\begin{wrapfigure}{i}{.5\textwidth}

\footnotesize
\paragraph{Sample float in wrap fig}
This is a sample float. \footnote{This is it 2} This is a sample float. This is a sample float. This is a sample float. This is a sample float. This is a sample float. This is a sample float. 
\end{wrapfigure}
\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: not specific to wrapfig, that applies to any box use `\footnotemark` to make the mark then add the text on the main page with `\footnotetext`

Comment: Unrelated to footnotes but it is really abuse of the markup to have a section heading such as `\paragraph` inside a figure.  `\paragraph` is a level 4 section heading and should only be used afer `\subsubsection`  not after `\section`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. Agree on the \paragraph remark. For the footnotes: If I understand well, I have to set up a specific series of footnotes for the wrapfig box? With a specific counter? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: you can use the standard  footnote counter but need \footnotemark inside the box just to make the raised number then use `\footnotetext{....}` on the main page which makes he footnote without making a mark at that point. here must be examples on this site

Comment: Understood. Thanks !

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314375/why-does-parbox-lose-footnotes?r=SearchResults&s=1|47.1271 .  If you want multiple footnotes, you can use \label and \ref to tie `\foonotemark` and `\footnotetext`.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455426/footnotes-in-subtables/455480?r=SearchResults&s=38|0.0000#455480